# Saving user's selection when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, local-storage

I currently have a page that displays data for different teams.

I have some data that the user can click on to make it an "on" or "off" state, showing a different icon for each. It's basically like a checklist, just without the physical checkboxes.

I would like to remember which of the "checkboxes" have been ticked, even after the user refreshes the page or closes the browser and returns later.

I have heard that `localStorage` is a good option, but I'm not sure how to use it in a situation like mine.

Currently I have this code:

```
team1 = {
    "information1": {
        "name": "tom",
        "age": "34"
    },
    "information2": {
        "name": "bob",
        "age": "20"
    },
};

team2 = {
    "information1": {
        "name": "betsy",
        "age": "27"
    },
    "information2": {
        "name": "brian",
        "age": "10"
    },
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#displayObject1").on("click", function() {
        switchData(team1);
    });

    $("#displayObject2").on("click", function() {
        switchData(team2);
    });
    $("#table").on("click", ".on", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("on");
        $(this).addClass("off");
    });
    $("#table").on("click", ".off", function() {
        $(this).addClass("on");
        $(this).removeClass("off");
    });
}); 


function switchData(object) {
    $("#table").contents("div").remove();
    if (!('rows' in object)) {
        var rows = [];
        Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
            if (key != 'rows') {
                rows.push($('<div class="row on">' + object[key].name + '</div>'));
            }
        });
        object.rows = rows;
    }
    object.rows.forEach(function (row) {
        $('#table').append(row);
    });
}
```

This makes rows to represent a team. The rows are retained with their color highlighting when the user looks at different teams during a browser session.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="displayObject1">
    <span>Display object 1</span>
</div>
<div><hr></div>
<div id="displayObject2">
    <span>Display object 2</span>
</div>
<div id="table">
</div>
```

And some CSS to show which list items are "on" and "off".

```
.on {
  background-color: green;
}
.off {
  background-color: red;
}
```

How can the page remember the color highlighting?

Comment: Do you have your markup as well? I can run it in JS Fiddle then and have a look to get it working.

Comment: Oops! Yep, added, my bad.

Comment: cookies, localstorage, server side saving via `onbeforeunload`, or `beforeunload` a lot of options here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to make the state of the team listings persist across browser sessions, you have to maintain a logical representation of the state and save it as a string whenever the state changes.

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) lets you encode a JavaScript object in a JSON string. For example, you can call a function like the following whenever you modify a global object named `pageState`:

```
function savePageState() {
  localStorage.setItem('pageState', JSON.stringify(pageState));
}
```

To retrieve the page state on page load, you can do something like this:

```
pageState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pageState'));
if (pageState === null) {
  pageState = {
    teams: teams
  };
  savePageState();
} else {
  teams = pageState.teams;
}
```

If `pageState` wasn't saved in a previous session, it is now created and saved to local storage. Otherwise, we consult `pageState` for data that we can use to restore the previous appearance of the team listings.

This code sample works on the assumption that the global object `teams` contains information relevant to the page state. You can add further properties to the page-state object to store more information. For example, to remember which team is currently displayed, you could do:

```
pageState.showTeam = teamName;
```

Then you can consult `pageState.showTeam` when you're initializing the page contents, perhaps like this:

```
if (teamName == pageState.showTeam) {
  showTeam(teamName);
  $(label).addClass('selected');
}
```

I have made a page that demonstrates this approach. I can't include it in my answer as a snippet because `localStorage` is sandboxed, but you can access the page here:

http://michaellaszlo.com/so/click-rows/

I've reorganized your team data to enable dynamic page initialization. Now each team object contains an array of person objects.

When the user clicks on a team member's name, the CSS class `selected` is toggled on the HTML element and the corresponding person object is updated by toggling its `selected` property:

```
function memberClick() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  this.person.selected = (this.person.selected ? false : true);
  savePageState();
};
```

The `showTeam` function checks a person's `selected` property when it's building its HTML representation, and adds the CSS class `selected` if appropriate. This is what makes it possible to restore the visual appearance of the page from the last session.

Comment: As a matter of fact I've been struggling to get this to work with my code. I'm going to send you an email going more in-depth if that's alright.

Comment: I don't have time to do one-on-one coaching. If you just need a couple of lines fixed, I might be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a flag in localStorage for each option using:

`localStorage.setItem('item1',true) //set the value to the checkbox's value`

and access it using:

`flagValue = localStorage.item1`

use these values similarly in your code once the document is ready to set the initial values of the checkboxes accordingly